# How to get brunch & sass-brunch to compile/include bootstrap.scss?

Tags: sass, brunch, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm new to brunch, but in trying to set it up with sass-brunch and bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.2 as npm-installed modules, I'm unable to get it to include bootstrap.scss. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a [small example project](https://github.com/bryanstearns/brunch-starter-bootstrap4).

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "simple-brunch",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "brunch": "^2.5.3",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

My brunch-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  config: {
    files: {
      javascripts: {
        joinTo: {
          'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/,
          'app.js': /^app/
        }
      },
      stylesheets: {
        joinTo: {
          'vendor.css': /^(?!app)/,
          'app.css': /^app/
        }
      }
    },

    npm: {
      styles: {
        bootstrap: ['scss/bootstrap.scss']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output from `brunch build -d` is below. `sass-brunch` is successfully being used to process `app/styles/main.scss` - there's a `brunch:pipeline` line that shows it. However, though a few lines near the top seem to indicate that it's found and compiled bootstrap's `bootstrap.scss`, and a `brunch:generate` line near the bottom appears to show that it's concatenated it to `vendor.css`, that file is empty except for the comment that points at `vendor.css.map` (`/*# sourceMappingURL=vendor.css.map*/`), and that map only contains `{"version":3,"sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","file":"public/vendor.css"}`.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Adding a `plugins.sass.options.includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss']` setting to brunch-config.js; no change in output.
- Adding a `paths.watched: ['app', 'test', 'vendor', 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss']` setting to brunch-config.js -- it now seems to find & watch all the files in that directory, but still isn't sending bootstrap.scss through the brunch pipeline to where sass-brunch can have a crack at it.

Here's the output:

```
brunch:config Trying to load brunch-config +0ms
brunch:plugins Loaded plugins: javascript-brunch, sass-brunch +66ms
brunch:watch add package.json +16ms
brunch:watch add brunch-config.js +0ms
brunch:watch add /Users/stearns/brunch-starter/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss +1ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss: isntModule=true isWrapped=false +3ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss +6ms
brunch:watch add app/application.js +1ms
brunch:list Reading app/application.js +0ms
brunch:file Init app/application.js: isntModule=false isWrapped=true +1ms
brunch:pipeline Compiling app/application.js @ JavaScriptCompiler +1ms
brunch:watch add app/assets/index.html +17ms
brunch:asset Init app/assets/index.html directory=app/assets/ relativePath=index.html destinationPath=public/index.html +1ms
brunch:watch add app/styles/main.scss +1ms
brunch:list Reading app/styles/main.scss +0ms
brunch:asset Copied app/assets/index.html +7ms
brunch:file Init app/styles/main.scss: isntModule=false isWrapped=false +1ms
brunch:pipeline Compiling app/styles/main.scss @ SassCompiler +0ms
brunch:pipeline Dependencies app/styles/main.scss @ SassCompiler +4ms
brunch:list Compiled app/styles/main.scss +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js +6ms
brunch:modules Wrapping application.js @ commonjs +0ms
brunch:list Compiled app/application.js +1ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/util.js +33ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/button.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/carousel.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/collapse.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/dropdown.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/modal.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/scrollspy.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tab.js +1ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tooltip.js +0ms
brunch:list Reading node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/popover.js +0ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js +0ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/util.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +1ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/button.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/carousel.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +1ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/collapse.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/dropdown.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/modal.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/scrollspy.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +1ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tab.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tooltip.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +0ms
brunch:file Init node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/popover.js: isntModule=true isWrapped=true +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/util.js +18ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/util.js +2ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/button.js +18ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/button.js +0ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js +54ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/carousel.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/carousel.js +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/collapse.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/collapse.js +0ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/dropdown.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/dropdown.js +0ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/modal.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/modal.js +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/scrollspy.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/scrollspy.js +4ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tab.js +2ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tab.js +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tooltip.js +1ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tooltip.js +1ms
brunch:modules Not wrapping (is vendor file) node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/popover.js +1ms
brunch:list Compiled node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/popover.js +1ms
brunch:write Writing 4/4 files +69ms
brunch:generate Concatenating [node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss] => public/vendor.css +2ms
brunch:generate Concatenating [app/application.js] => public/app.js +2ms
brunch:generate Concatenating [app/styles/main.scss] => public/app.css +2ms
brunch:generate Concatenating [node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/button.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/carousel.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/collapse.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/dropdown.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/modal.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/popover.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/scrollspy.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tab.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/tooltip.js, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/util.js] => public/vendor.js +3ms
brunch:common Writing public/vendor.css +33ms
brunch:common Writing public/app.js +0ms
brunch:common Writing public/app.css +0ms
brunch:common Writing public/vendor.js +1ms
brunch:common Writing public/app.css.map +4ms
brunch:common Writing public/app.js.map +1ms
brunch:common Writing public/vendor.css.map +0ms
brunch:common Writing public/vendor.js.map +8ms
27 Mar 03:52:23 - info: compiled 15 files into 4 files, copied index.html in 776ms
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/bassjobsen/brunch-bootstrap4 and start an issue i you've any questions about it

Comment: Thanks, @bass -- that's a skeleton that would build bootstrap4 into my app's source code; I prefer to maintain Bootstrap as a separate dependency, to make it easier to upgrade later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`npm.styles` should only be used to add compiled CSS from `node_modules`. In this case, if you didn't want to customize bootstrap, you could use

```
npm: {
  styles: {
    bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
  }
}
```

Or, to use its sass version (to customize it and so on), you would need to:

1. `plugins.sass.options.includePaths = ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss']`, as you tried. This simply *adds* bootstrap to sass' *load path*
2. actually `@import 'bootstrap'` in your SASS file. Otherwise, how would SASS know if it should include that one or not, and where to include?

Note that in this case you will have one big css file as the output (app.css)

Comment: For the first option make sure you have `css-brunch` installed - ran into a similar issue where the styles in the npm option were not being pulled in.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that if you missed with _package name_ or _path to CSS_ you **won't get any warning on it**. At least I am not, what cost me some valuable time.